# Android Studio Re-installs Every time

Tags: android-studio

I have already changed my path variables and installed Android Studio Bundle. I am also able to access the page to create a new project. However, once I exit out of the studio and reopen, I am forced to reinstall everything again which takes 10 minutes. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it is not re installing android studio just take some time to load android studio if it shows progress bar in the below line of dialog.